# Load script file from internal jar

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a java multi-module application and in one of them, I need to load a script to generate the DB in memory with H2.

This same module will be used in other applications as a dependency to generate the data model in memory.
I have browsed endless responses and applied almost all solutions, but it only works within the eclipse.

When I generate the war, when deploying it in JBoss, it gives the famous FileNotFoundException error.

When I use the library as a dependency in another project, the error is the same.
I have changed the script in different places of the module, but the result is the same.
I have placed it in ***resources/script***, ***resources***, inside a ***com.app.frameworkrest.persistence.scripts*** package and when compiling, the file is excluded from the resulting jar.
I would appreciate some help to solve this problem.

```
    private void createTables(Connection conDestin) throws SQLException, IOException {
        File script = null; 
        try {
            ClassPathResource rs = new ClassPathResource("META-INF/scripts/FRWK_REST_SCHEMA.SQL");
            script = rs.getFile();
            script = new File(MemoryDatabaseConfig.class.getResource("/com/app/frameworkrest/persistence/scripts/FRWK_REST_SCHEMA.SQL").getFile());

            script = ResourceUtils.getFile("FRWK_REST_SCHEMA.SQL");
            script = new File(MemoryDatabaseConfig.class.getResource("/scripts/FRWK_REST_SCHEMA.SQL").getFile());

            Resource rs = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:scripts/FRWK_REST_SCHEMA.SQL");
            URL url = getClass().getResource("../scripts/FRWK_REST_SCHEMA.SQL");
            File file = new File(url.getPath());
            script = rs.getFile();
            script = new File(MemoryDatabaseConfig.class.getResource("META-INF/scripts/FRWK_REST_SCHEMA.SQL").getFile());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ClassPathResource rs = new ClassPathResource("scripts/FRWK_REST_SCHEMA.SQL");
            script = rs.getFile();
        }
        LOGGER.info("Loading schema! {}", script.getPath());
        RunScript.execute(conDestin, new FileReader(script));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `ClassPathResource#getFile()` javaDoc:

   > java.io.FileNotFoundException if the resource cannot be resolved as absolute file path, i.e. if the resource is not available in a `file system`
2. `ResourceUtils#getFile(String)` javaDoc:

   > Resolve the given resource location to a {@code java.io.File}, i.e. to a file in the `file system`
3. `new File(String)` should also be used with `file system` files
4. `new FileReader(File)` should also be used with `file system` files

to load the script files from the internal jar, you have to change:

1. `ClassPathResource#getFile()` to `ClassPathResource#getInputStream()`
2. `new File(String)` to `url.openStream()`
3. `new FileReader(File)` to `new InputStreamReader(InputStream)`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta.
Funciona perfectamente!

`
private void createTables(Connection conMemDB) throws SQLException, IOException {
  Reader inputStreamReader = null;
  try {
   InputStream inputStream = MemoryDatabaseConfig.class.getResourceAsStream("/scripts/FRWK_REST_SCHEMA.SQL");
   inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   LOGGER.error("Error trying to create memory database!", e);
  }
  RunScript.execute(conMemDB, inputStreamReader);
  LOGGER.info("Memory database was created!");
 }
`

Comment: you are welcome, I would also recommend you move `RunScript.execute(conMemDB, inputStreamReader);` inside `try` block after `inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);` to avoid `NullPointerException` if an exception occurs